# How can I compile with a specific Solidity version in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity

I'm using Visual Code with some Solidity extensions. I am obliged to compile with version 0.4.17 only for no reason. I 've tried some suggestions around: RemoteVersion: "latest", local version, npm install etc,... but none of them works.
This a sample contract from CryptoZombies lesson so I haven't deployed yet. I'm afraid this bug won't let me deploy later.

[Solidity Version Bug Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT7Ug.png)

Comment: Yes I wanted to do something like this

Answer (score -2):

I think you should update the truffle, and solc version, so the compiler version should be  higher.

Comment: I don't use truffle. I tried npm install solc locally. The problem is still there.

Comment: when you write "solcjs --version" what version is printing in the console/terminal ?

Comment: I get 0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.Emscripten.clang, which is clearly the latest version. But inside Visual Code, it still forces me to compile with 0.4.17 only

Comment: have you tried to  reinstall the extension for the vs code, sometimes it makes problems, and you are using the one from Juan Blanco ? Also have you tried to remove the option for the remote version in the user settings in the vs code ?

Comment: i tried remoteVersion option before. And yes, I'm using Juan Blanco one. But not just that, I'm also using 5 different solidity extensions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT7Ug.png